# Android in-app billing: virtual money

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to use in-app billing to implement virtual money: a user can for example buy sets of 50, 100 and 250 coins.

I'm wondering how I would manage the number of coins each user has. Do I have to manage that myself or does Android provide something for this?
If not, how would I store this information? UID won't work if the user has multiple devices, but I'd prefer not to store email-addresses.

Any thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is have the data stored on a server and access it through a Web service. I initially stored it locally, but quite a few rooted users started editing the app data and getting extra money.

Essentially, I use in app purchases to have the user pay. When I receive confirmation that the transaction was successful, I send a pre defined string to my server. I don't send raw numeric values like 50 as a user could then make it 500 and get extra cash. Instead, the server matches the string it receives with a list of strings. If there is a match, it adds that much money to the user's account. If there isn't a match, it tells the app there was an error.

Comment: I think this is indeed the way to go, but how do you store the user data? What values do you use? (UID, email address, ...)? Also, do you encrypt the data you send? A user could intercept messages and send them again. And again.

Comment: I use a nonce to make sure that one purchase is only added once to a user's account.

Comment: And do you store uid's, email addresses,...?

Comment: The user is allowed to use my app without an account, but if they make a purchase, I require them to sign up. I then store the email id along with the wifi mac address if available. The user can use the same account across multiple devices, but I only store the mac address of the initial device.